# Including files in web.xml

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, web.xml

I'm in the process of writing unit tests for a JEE5 web service. The behaviour of the web service depends on the attributes set in the `web.xml` file. I'm wanting to therefore split my `web.xml` into a constant part and a part that is changed around inbetween test runs.

To see if it's actually possible, I've tried to see if I can split out the `welcome-file-list` attribute. Using [some instructions I found](http://futurevsfantasy.livejournal.com/3626.html) I've come up the following:

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE web-app
    PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
    "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" [
  <!ENTITY fragment SYSTEM "fragment.xml">
]>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
    <listener>
        <listener-class>com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>NewWebService</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>NewWebService</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/NewWebService</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
  &fragment;
</web-app>
```

**fragment.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<welcome-file-list>
  <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

However, I'm getting validation errors on the `web.xml` file:

> Attribute "version" must be declared for element type "web-app". [7]
>   Attribute "xmlns" must be declared for element type "web-app". [7]
>   Attribute "xmlns:xsi" must be declared for element type "web-app". [7]
>   Attribute "xsi:schemaLocation" must be declared for element type "web-app". [7]

I get the feeling that using a web app v2.3 DTD and a web app v2.5 schema inside the same file is the problem, but I don't know how I'm going to be able to get around it.

(Any other approaches in splitting a web.xml file into smaller chunks would be welcome too!)

**Update**

If I remove the DTD reference like so...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE web-app[
  <!ENTITY fragment SYSTEM "fragment.xml">
]>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
etc, etc, etc.
```

...it appears as though the validation process ignores the `web-app_2_5.xsd` file:

> Element type "web-app" must be declared. [5]
>   Element type "listener" must be declared. [6]
>   Element type "listener-class" must be declared. [7]
>   Element type "servlet" must be declared. [9]
>   etc, etc, etc.

Comment: DO NOT DO THIS! You're basically utilizing a Tomcat-specific security exploit which is fixed in newer Tomcat versions and not necessarily present in different servers. In other words, the webapp with such a web.xml is unportable. Related issue report: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1069911

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up adding a hook into my web service that checks for the presence of an [eproperties](http://code.google.com/p/eproperties/) file. If it finds one, it knows that it is in testing mode and instead of using the values specified in `web.xml`, it pulls them from the properties file. Not very elegant but at least it works. The properties file is copied to the `WEB-INF` directory by the JUnit test during the `@BeforeClass` method. Given the success of this method I've been wondering whether `web.xml` is the best place to store web application settings anyway...